# UILocalNotification Not Firing iOS 8.4

Tags: swift, timezone, uilocalnotification, ios8.4

```
Printing description of localNotification:
```

> {fire date =
>   Wednesday, August 5, 2015 at 9:00:00 AM India Standard Time, time zone
>   = (null), repeat interval = NSCalendarUnitDay, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Thursday,
>   August 6, 2015 at 9:00:00 AM India Standard Time, user info = (null)}

As you see the Time is 9:00:00 AM morning but it never fires here what i am doing

- I am testing on Simulator by changing my Mac Time , is that the case ?
- i have also tired to change the my mac time to next fire date , Still not working .
- will these work perfectly in Live device ?

## Update Code

```
 var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
      //  calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        let comp = NSDateComponents()
        //comp.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        comp.day = NSDate().day()
        comp.month = NSDate().month()
        comp.year = NSDate().year()


        comp.hour = date.hour()
        comp.minute = date.minute()
        var grouptimestamp = calendar.dateFromComponents(comp)?.getCurrentTimeStemp()

        var minutes = self.getMinutestFromTimestemp(NSDate.getCurrentTimeStemp() - grouptimestamp!)

        if minutes > 59 {
            println("Missed")
        }else if minutes < -5 {
            println("Early")
        }else{
            println("Takenow")
        }

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.alertAction = "Myplan"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Woww it works!!"
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(grouptimestamp!))
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the you have not set the `timezone` to the system timezone. By default, it sets the timezone according to your location and not according to the system time. 
Try adding this to your code:

```
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

This will change you notification timezone to the system timezone and then the notification will fire up if you change the time.

Hope this helps :)